# Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using the Webclient class to download a websites HTML.  The code is pretty straight forward:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

            client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

            string web = client.DownloadString(url);
```

But sometimes I'll get this error message that I cant reproduce.  It seems to happen randomly:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

I have no idea what that error means or how I can fix it.  Any guesses?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the WebClient in a using statement? (not sure if WebClient is disposable or not... )

Comment: possible duplicate of [An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608431/an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-in-your-host-machine)

Comment: @RobertH I dispose the class, I just forgot to paste that part of the code.

Comment: A few questions: Does your client run for a long period of time, or multiple times in rapid succession? If it is a long running process is it possible the class is not getting disposed of correctly? If it is rapid succession is it possible that you are flooding the network resulting in lost packets? Have you set any timeout information? Is it a possibility that Host is referring to the host of the url you are downloading data from? When the issue occurs are you having network issues (latency, dropped packets etc )?

Comment: @RobertH My client is a webcrawler, so its run for very long periods of time, as well as rapid succession.  I also have not set any timeout information.

Answer (score -1):

First cast to NetException(or smth like that) to trace the exception message.
Might be multiple reasons for that to happen (unsuported method for example :)).
If there is nothing special in the net exception then check firewall or proxy.
If you are using a proxy try setting it through code or through config.